# Deserializing a JSON Array response using Spring Webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am having a problem deserializing this JSON array using Spring Webclient:

```
[
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "category": "Task",
        "status": "Not Yet Completed"
    },
    {
        "id": "54321",
        "category": "Task",
        "status": "Completed"
    },
    ....
]
```

I am retrieving this this JSON response using WebClient in this block of code here:

```
public Mono<List<TaskHistoryView>> getTaskHistory() {

        return this.webClient
                .get()
                .uri(Url)
                .headers(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth(config.getBasicAuth().getUsername(),config.getBasicAuth().getPassword()))
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(TaskHistoryView.class)
                .collectList();

}
```

Here is the TaskHistoryView Class I am trying to map it to:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TaskHistoryView {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id;
  @JsonProperty("category")
  private String category;
  @JsonProperty("status")
  private String status;
}
```

When I send a request into my API, I just get empty array brackets as a response:

```
[]
```

I believe it is some issue with how I am mapping the JSON array to that TaskHistoryView.class, but am not sure what the issue is. I have tried everything from this existing thread with a similar issue: [Deserialize a json array to objects using Jackson and WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48598233/deserialize-a-json-array-to-objects-using-jackson-and-webclient), however I keep running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you return a `Mono` you could directly use the `bodyToMono` operator. And since your return type is a parameterized type `List<TaskHistoryView>` you need to use the `ParameterizedTypeReference` class to wrap the generic type:

```java
    return this.webClient
            .get()
            .uri(Url)
            .headers(headers -> headers.setBasicAuth(config.getBasicAuth().getUsername(),config.getBasicAuth().getPassword()))
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<TaskHistoryView>>() { });
```

Comment: Good suggestion but no luck with this! Still just returns empty array brackets.

Comment: @Noouhh I will need more information like how are you calling the method etc, because I just built a service with exactly this scenario and it works just fine.